# Sql trigger with if then else construction

Tags: sql, postgresql

Thera is trigger in PostgreSQL 8.4:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateMarkers()
  RETURNS trigger AS
  $$
  BEGIN
IF NEW.status='Новый' THEN
    UPDATE markers SET statusId=0;
    RETURN NEW;
ELSE IF NEW.status='В работе' THEN
    UPDATE markers SET statusId=2;
    RETURN NEW;
ELSE IF NEW.status='Завершен' THEN
    UPDATE markers SET statusId=3;
    RETURN NEW;
ESLE
    UPDATE markers SET statusId=4;
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And i get syntax error in `ESLE` line.
Whats can be wrong?

Comment: +1 for extremely funny question

Comment: @skytz: Your words make me hurt. (

Comment: it happens to the best of us

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have written ESLE instead of `ELSE`....
Your new query should be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateMarkers()
  RETURNS trigger AS
  $$
  BEGIN
IF NEW.status='Новый' THEN
    UPDATE markers SET statusId=0;
    RETURN NEW;
ELSEIF NEW.status='В работе' THEN
    UPDATE markers SET statusId=2;
    RETURN NEW;
ELSEIF NEW.status='Завершен' THEN
    UPDATE markers SET statusId=3;
    RETURN NEW;
ELSE
    UPDATE markers SET statusId=4;
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

@edit:
ELSE IF need to be together:ELSEIF

Comment: Yeah mistake. But now i get error in next line.

Comment: Ok i found mistake: `ELSE IF --> ELSIF`.

Answer (score 5):

Or, simpler and faster in your case with one `UPDATE` command using a ["simple" **`CASE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatemarkers()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN

UPDATE markers
SET    statusid = 
   CASE NEW.status
    WHEN 'Новый'    THEN 0
    WHEN 'В работе' THEN 2;
    WHEN 'Завершен' THEN 3;
    ELSE 4
   END;

RETURN NEW;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This simple form is good, since you are updating in any case. Works in Postgres 8.4, too.

Comment: This code look very nice.